# Writing Calorie data to Google Fit using Flutter GoogleFitAPI

Tags: flutter, google-fit-api

Is there a way for Writing Calorie data to Google Fit using Flutter GoogleFitAPI

Comment: I think there is solution to your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123898/calories-expenditure-using-google-fit-api

Comment: This solution is for reading calorie data from Google Fit API using Java, I need to write calorie data to Google Fit API using the "googleapis" package with Flutter

Comment: I couldn't find any example for the task using googleapis package